# How can I put images on a django template from another server?

Tags: python, django, image, static

I'm trying to make a webpage with `django` and I would like to put a lot and I mean a lot of images, the images are already in a server(`10.10.10.5/myImages`), if I use the method of `django`, `django` would copy all the images to his static route folder, and I don't want to do that.

How can I load all those images in my Template without copy all the images on my static route folder. I also don't want that anybody can see the images route in the code. (i.e. when you click on a web page "see the code of this web page ")

I would like to put something like

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static_dir'),'10.10.10.5/myImages/'
```

Comment: you might want to look [**here**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/deployment/) and [**here**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#staticfiles-storage)

Answer (score 0):

Django doesn't care where the images are. Just set the `src` of the image tags in your templates to point to the correct URL on the other server.

Comment: But i dont want to show where the images are inside the html code.

Comment: What? You have to do that anyway, wherever they are. You always need a URL pointing at the STATIC host, whatever it is.

Comment: i mean the code in the web browser, the html that the users can see